# Customize the I like it ribbon

Tags: ribbon

Is it possible to customize the ribbon that shows I like it and show something like below?

[image]

I know we can hide and style the default `I like it` and `Tags&Notes` buttons, we are looking to add new buttons on that same row.

Steps to customize:

```
http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2011/08/sharepoint-2010-replace-i-like-it-and.html
```

**Update1**:

It is easy to add custom buttons in the Page ribbon. 
[image]

I am looking for a way to add them in the Browse view ribbon
[image]

Comment: One thing you might want to consider is that SP 2013 does not have a ribbon for the "Browse" tab by default. For easier upgrading you may want to create your own tab.

Answer (score 1):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407458(v=office.14).aspx

The Ribbon is defined as [XML with these elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407290%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

The location of the button can be defined using the location attribute. [Here is a full list of default locations and a way to look-up others.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537543%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

**Example**:
Create a new feature in visual studio and edit the feature.xml file:

```
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"
         Id="afe52f83-a20e-42d4-8aa7-35d8c5fdfb39"
         Title="Custom title"
         Scope="Web"
         ImageUrl="button image url">
</Feature>
```

Edit the Elements.xml file to something like this (you may need to change the location for the button to show at the correct time):

```
<CustomAction

    Id="CustomRibbonButton1"
    RegistrationId="101"
    RegistrationType="List"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
    Sequence="5"
    Title="Alert">

    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Manage.Controls._children">
          <Button
              Id="Ribbon.Documents.New.TestButton"
              Alt="Alert"
              Sequence="5"
              Command="Test_Button"
              Image32by32="/_layouts/images/32x32 image location"
              Image16by16="/_layouts/images/16x16 image location"
              LabelText="Move Documents"
              TemplateAlias="o1" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>

      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
          Command="Test_Button"
          CommandAction="javascript:alert('My custom button!');" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>

    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
```

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a way to add similar button s in the browse view. I updated the question with the pictures.

Comment: Although I have not done that before it should be a matter of changing the CommandUIDefinition location attribute. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537543(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the Browse tab is accessible from code. If you look into the master page, you'll see that the browse tab is accessible as HTML, and the social buttons are a user control. They don't use the ribbon controls in the same manner as the Page tab.

HTH